# How do I create a new Objective C (.m + .h) on Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I just upgraded to Xcode 6 and I am really confused as to how I can create a new class. I want to make a new UIViewController class and UTableViewController class but I dont know what to click on. The only one that seems to come out with both a .h and a .m is the category class however where did all the methods go?
In Xcode 5, you had viewDidLoad/didSelectRowAtIndexPath and all other such methods that usually just got loaded up when I made a new file. Has Apple decided to scratch that or I am missing something,

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File > New File > Cocoa Class

[image]

Make sure to select iOS > Source if you're doing an iOS Proj.

Comment: The question is for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same as always.

File | New | File...

Select "Source" under the iOS section. Then select Cocoa Touch Class. Click Next. Select the base class and give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

Goto File -> New File -> iOS Source-> Cocoa Touch Class

Make sure the language is set to Objective C not swift